# Transform different image if specific id or order

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I have a masonry type image grid layout and I need to specify a different image transform for just the 2nd and fourth images in this grid.

Does the image ID relate to the order or to the specific image? How could I include a conditional in my code to output the largeIndexHalf image transform for the 2nd and 4th image?

```
{% set asset = entry.portraits %}
{% if asset | length %}
{% for asset in entry.portraits %}
<div class="item"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl('largeIndex') }}" /></div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that like so:

```
{% for asset in entry.portraits %}
    {% if loop.index == 2 or loop.index == 4 %}
        {% set transform = 'largeIndexHalf' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set transform = 'largeIndex' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="item"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl(transform) }}" /></div>
{% endfor %}
```

or more simply (making use of the [containment operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) (`in`) and the ternary operator (`? :`):

```
{% for asset in entry.portraits %}
    {% set transform = loop.index in [2, 4] ? 'largeIndexHalf' : 'largeIndex' %}
    <div class="item"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl(transform) }}" /></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you. Example here: http://alisilversteinportraits.com/

Answer (score 3):

To better understand, do you want transform for all **even** iterations on the array? If so, Twig's [`cycle`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html) function should do what you want:

```
{% set asset = entry.portraits %}
{% if asset | length %}
   {% for asset in entry.portraits %}
      {% set transform = cycle(['largeIndex', 'largeIndexHalf'], loop.index0) %}
      <div class="item"><img src="{{ asset.getUrl(transform) }}" /></div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**Edit**

Rereading the question and Brandon's answer, I may have misinterpreted that you do indeed *just* want the 2nd and 4th image. I'll leave my answer for posterity for people looking to do an even / odd thing though.