# Adding class based on length

Tags: templating, plugin-neo

I'm using Neo to allow my client to be able to create a content grid with child blocks. Now I'm wondering, is there a way that I can change the class of the output based on the number of items?  For example, if there are two items I'd like to have the class `grid-one-half` and if there are three `grid-one-third` etc. to give my client more flexibility in making grids.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by modifying the code from [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8630/transform-different-image-if-specific-id-or-order) on image transforms. Here's the basics of my markup.

```
<div class="{% if loop.length == 2 %}grid-one-half{% elseif loop.length == 3 %}grid-one-third{% elseif loop.length == 4 %}grid-one-quarter{% endif %} grid-item">
</div>
```