# Random transforms

Tags: craft3, image-transforms, image

We are using a masonry grid, with 3 image sizes (different heights). The images are (one of) the banner image(s) from the news entries. We played around with [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8630/transform-different-image-if-specific-id-or-order), however this doesn't work as we need to limit the image output - per entry - to only one. Running on the latest Craft 3 version.

How can we, randomly, have one out of three image transforms, applied to the banner image of each entry?

This is the code:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="grid-items js-isotope js-grid-items">
            {% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').limit(10).all()  %}
            {% set image = entry.bannerImage.one() %}
            <div class="grid-item js-isotope-item js-grid-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="item"><img alt=""  src="{{ image.getUrl( 'masonryLarge' )}}"/></div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="card-posted"><a href="#">{{ entry.author }}</a> on {{ entry.postDate | date('M d, Y') }}</div>
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{ entry.title }}</h4>
                        <div class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel auctorol est. Integer nunc ipsum...</div>
                        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="card-read-more">Continue</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The transforms are: masonryLarge, masonryMedium & masonrySmall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Twigs [Random](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/random.html) function

```
{{ random(['masonryLarge', 'masonryMedium', 'masonrySmall']) }}
```

So you could do something like

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').limit(10).all()  %}
    {% set image = entry.bannerImage.one() %}
    <div class="grid-item js-isotope-item js-grid-item">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item"><img alt=""  src="{{ image.getUrl( random(['masonryLarge', 'masonryMedium', 'masonrySmall']) )}}"/></div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-posted"><a href="#">{{ entry.author }}</a> on {{ entry.postDate | date('M d, Y') }}</div>
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ entry.title }}</h4>
                <div class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect etur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel auctorol est. Integer nunc ipsum...</div>
                <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="card-read-more">Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can use Twigs [Cycle](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html) function

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').limit(10).all()  %}
    {% set transform = cycle(['masonryLarge', 'masonryMedium', 'masonrySmall'], loop.index0) %}
{% endfor %}
```